# Buttons to Activities

Tags: javascript, android

I'm new to Android Studio but doing my best to learn it. 
This is the case I came up with and unfortunately can't find an answer even though it seems basics.

My app starts with [3 buttons (Workouts, Results, Info)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwjkk.png)

F.e When I click on "WORKOUTS" I want to get to the Activity which I called WorkoutsActivity.java which has [12 buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc3PH.png).

When I click on "RESULTS" I want to get to the activity ActivityResults.java etc...

- What is the code to link these different 3 buttons to different 3 Activities?
- Do I need to create 12 new activities for buttons in WorkoutsActivity.java? (is that how android works?)

I very appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: This might help you https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here are few concepts you need to understand before I publish the source code : **Layouts**, **Views**, **Activities**, **Intents** and **Events**.

Views are visible UI elements such as texts, images, buttons, progress bars, rating bars, etc.

Layouts are invisible UI elements who displays views in a defined order such as a row, a column or a position relative to other views (toRightOf, toLeftOf, etc.) They are also called containers.

Activities is like a 'page' that handle a single task. It contains views and layouts (and even more) and a context.

Intents are a kind of bridge to go to an activity from an other. There are a lot of things to learn about them, but think basically like a bridge.

Finally, events are the way the user interacts with views : clicks, touches, drag and drop, ... They contains listeners and handlers such as *OnClickListener* and *OnClick*. Obviously, the first one listen to and the second handle the event.

---

```
package com.learnandroid.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button myButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.learnandroid.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*activity_main.xml*

Do not forget to declare every activity in your Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.learnandroid.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

Comment: You building my "android mindset" just in seconds - that is so helpful. I hope I will be able to get that source code to get more sense about OnClickListener event and play around with it.

Comment: Ok. Looks good, but I see this is the source code for one button to go to another activity. How does the source code looks like if I have 3 buttons like in my case I described?

Comment: It will looks the same. Each button needs to be inflated and listened the way I show you. You will needs 1 activity for each and one button node in xml for each

Comment: Just copy paste myButton instructions for myButton2 and myButton3.

Answer (score 0):

You can react to a button click event with the setOnClickListener method

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener...
```

It will then generate the onClick handler automatically.

And use intent in it to start a new activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(from.this, to.class);

startActivity(i);
```

Obviously, you need to change *from* and *to* to activity names

Comment: Wow hold on Champ... As I said I'm just starting with android studio and java in general. Your comment makes sense and I really appreciate it. Could you start from "public class..." It might sound silly but I'm looking for entire code here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo-code you need to follow :

```
Class

    Button (3 times)

    onCreate

           Inflate buttons (3 times)

           Click events (3 times)

    End of onCreate

End of class
```

Herie is the result this pseudo-code should give :

```
package com.learnandroid.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button myButton;
    Button myButton2;
    Button myButton3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);
        myButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton3);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        myButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FourthActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.learnandroid.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Button 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Button 3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do not forget to declare your activities in the Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.learnandroid.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".FourthActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Second, Third and Fourth are actually empty.

You can use the **layout_weight** attribute if you need your buttons to match the 1/3 size of the screen.

Comment: As I said before I will have more time to post the answer tomorrow. I will let you try by yourself. Read our comments again and will see together tomorrow :)

Comment: Woke up today excited to see the solution but still waiting... :)

Comment: Thanks Alexandre!!

Comment: Can you validate the answer for further purpose please ? :)